# Cant pip install dlib

Tags: python, cmake, dlib

I have `Cmake` installed but when I try: `pip install dlib` I get the following error:

```
CMake Error at C:/Users/Aristo/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install 4xetg9ok/dlib/dlib/external/pybind11/tools/FindPythonLibsNew.cmake:124 (message):
      Python config failure: Python is 32-bit, chosen compiler is 64-bit
```

Answer (score 0):

#### You have to do three things

1. Add cmake to your path (Ex : c\program Files\cmake\bin)
2. pip install cmake
3. pip install dlib

### and done

Comment: What do you mean add cmake to my path? I just installed it, do I need to to do something else?

Comment: @alex999ar ,you need to add path of cmake in your enviroment variables path